# How to create cell with multiple styles in excel using HSSFSheet Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, export, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I am creating a script for export document as excel.

How to have cell value like "**Name:** Mark **DOB:** 11-11-2014" by merging few cells?

Comment: Can you add more info and some code so that its easier to solve your problem. I have suggested another library below which i found very easy to use.

Answer (score 8):

What you need to do is create a [RichTextString](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html) for your cell. That's the way of applying different formatting / styles to different parts of the same cell for display in Excel

You'll want to review the [POI "Working With Rich Text" example](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html) for more on how to use it, but broadly it'll be something like

```
    Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
    RichTextString rt = new XSSFRichTextString("The quick brown fox");

    Font font1 = wb.createFont();
    font1.setBoldWeight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    rt.applyFont(0, 10, font1);

    Font font2 = wb.createFont();
    font2.setItalic(true);
    font2.setUnderline(XSSFFont.U_DOUBLE);
    rt.applyFont(10, 19, font2);

    Font font3 = wb.createFont();
    font3.setBoldWeight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);
    rt.append(" Jumped over the lazy dog", font3);

    cell.setCellValue(rt);
```

That should give you a cell with a mixture of bold, italic+underline and normal

Comment: what is that 0,10 and 10,19 ?

Comment: Look at the linked javadocs, those are the offsets within the cell's text you want the styling to apply to

Comment: Are you sure Font.setBold will work? Should it not be `XSSFFont font1 = (XSSFFont)wb.createFont(); font1.setBold(true);` or `font1.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);` ?

Comment: Depends if you're using HSSF or XSSF. I believe the above ought to work for both, but I haven't actually tried it...

Comment: Hm, no, the interface Font has no method setBold. https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html

Comment: Hmm, how strange! Corrected

Comment: Though if you look at the javadocs, you will see [Font.setBold(boolean)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html#setBold%28boolean%29) showing up now...

Comment: Hm, not for me. There is only https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFont.html#setBold%28boolean%29 in class XSSFFont, not in interface Font. And it is setBoldweight and not setBoldWeight.

Comment: Refresh your page, you might be surprised ;-)

Comment: Its not working, we have to think alternative option for "Font".

Comment: @Gagravarr: *g* Yes the documentation has changed now. But nevertheless I got a compiler error for Font.setBold with my POI version. Will try this evening whether the apache guys have updated my local jar files too ;-).

Answer (score 7):

I have created a short complete example for this.

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;


class RichTextTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

  RichTextString richString = new XSSFRichTextString( "Name: Mark DOB: 11-11-2014" );
                                                     //^0  ^4     ^11^14
  Font fontBold = wb.createFont();
  //fontBold.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
  fontBold.setBold(true);

  richString.applyFont( 0, 4, fontBold );
  richString.applyFont( 11, 14, fontBold );
  cell.setCellValue(richString);


  try {
   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
   wb.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.flush();
   fileOut.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }

 }
}
```

For further reading see documentation.

How to create workbook, sheet and cells: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateCells

How to use Richtext: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRichTextString.html

The Font interface: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [JXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/simplebeans.html) ?

Using xls templates you can read and write data from Excel. Its very simple to use.