# Multiple Styles to Excel Cell POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to apply colour to cell as well as Format Cell value(e.g. Date,Amount).But when I am applying two Cell Style only the last style is gets applied on cell.

```
//before this colourCellStyle and dateCellStyle are the formatting style
cell9 = row.createCell(9);
cell9.setCellValue(getLoadDate());
cell9.setCellStyle(colourCellStyle);
cell9.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
```

Comment: cell9.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle); is overriding cell9.setCellStyle(colourCellStyle); property

Comment: Yes ,you are correct.How to give both styles to same cell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885834/how-to-create-cell-with-multiple-styles-in-excell-using-hssfsheet-apache-poi might be helpful

Comment: I checked that thread but XSSFRichTextString is used for strings and it has applyFont method for styling.

Comment: A cell can only ever have one style applied. What happens if you create a third style that has both the colour and the date format on it?

Comment: I'm not getting what you want to ask?..Last applied style is persisted. I want to apply multiple style.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Multiple cell styles cannot be applied to a single `Cell`.  The last cell style applied will overwrite any pre-existing cell style on the `Cell`.  Setting multiple `CellStyle`s won't combined the set attributes of each style.

The solution is to create another `CellStyle` that has the desired attributes of both of the other `CellStyle`s.  You can use [the `cloneStyleFrom` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#cloneStyleFrom(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle)) to start with the attributes of one `CellStyle`.

```
CellStyle combined = workbook.createCellStyle();
combined.cloneStyleFrom(colourCellStyle);
combined.setDataFormat(dateCellStyle.getDataFormat());
// You can copy other attributes to "combined" here if desired.

cell9.setCellStyle(combined);
```

This technique can be generalized to clone any existing cell style and copy individual attributes from a second existing cell style.  As always, reuse any existing `CellStyle`s, but if a different combination of attributes is required, then you must create and use a new `CellStyle`.

Comment: That's great if the combinations are limited. In my case I'm building a spread sheet and I don't necessarily know all combinations. The styles are driven by data. Wonder if this is a design issue with POI or if it's inherent with Excel's format.

Comment: Section "18.3.1.4 c (Cell)" of ECMA-376-1:2016 indicates "s (Style Index). The index of this cell's style. Style records are stored in the Styles Part. The possible values for this attribute are defined by the W3C XML Schema `unsignedInt` datatype." It looks like it allows only one style.

Comment: Note that you can dynamically create a style, then store it in a Map and if you need it again you use the same style. Naming might be an issue. BTW it looks like the number of styles is limited.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a map of styles and then you can use different styles throughout the java program.

For example

```
Map<String, CellStyle> cellStyles = new HashMap<String, CellStyle>();
DataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();

XSSFCellStyle cellStyle;
XSSFFont font;

cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();

cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
cellStyle.setAlignment(cellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION);   
font = workbook.createFont();
font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)16);
font.setFontName("Calibri");                                            
cellStyle.setFont(font);
cellStyles.put("header_cell_style", cellStyle);

cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle(); 
cellStyle.setAlignment(cellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION);
font = workbook.createFont();
font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)12);
font.setFontName("Calibri");                   
cellStyle.setFont(font);
cellStyles.put("normal_cell_style", cellStyle);

cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setAlignment(cellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION);       
cellStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("dd-mmm-yyyy"));
font = workbook.createFont();
font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)12);
font.setFontName("Calibri");                   
cellStyle.setFont(font);
cellStyles.put("date_cell_style", cellStyle);

cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setAlignment(cellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION);       
cellStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("dd-mmm-yyyy"));
font = workbook.createFont();
font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)16);
font.setFontName("Calibri");                   
cellStyle.setFont(font);
cellStyles.put("header_date_cell_style", cellStyle);

return cellStyles;
```

and then use this map like

```
Map<String, CellStyle> multipleCellStyles = createMultipleExcelCellStyles(workbook);

headerCellD1.setCellStyle(multipleCellStyles.get("header_cell_style"));

cellB.setCellStyle(multipleCellStyles.get("normal_cell_style"));

cellC.setCellStyle(multipleCellStyles.get("date_cell_style"));
```

Comment: this is a nice way to organise the code but it doesn't help to apply more than one style to the same cell (e.g apply 2 defined XSSFCellStyle to the same cell)...